# How to insert the owner of a related object into the journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I am building a journey that will be **triggered by the Quote object** status being updated in Sales Cloud. However, the **owner of the related Opportunity** object is who I want to be inserted into the journey. (Unfortunately, the two objects are not owned by the same user.) The only options I'm presented with are in the screenshot below.

Is there a way to achieve this?

*(I also tried building this the other way, triggered by the Opportunity stage, but they want to include information from the Quote in the entry data and this can be a one-to-many relationship.)*

[image: The only options I get for who to inject into the journey]